# How to print out a table from mySQL database inside a html/php page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i am trying to print out this table [image: the table] from phpmyadmin to my html/php page as a normal table. this is my coding for the page [image: the page]
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: you are trying to print users and scores

Comment: yea i am trying to print out the users and scores @lyndact

Comment: ok i can help you with this

Comment: thank you.. i would really appreciate that @lyndact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like You were Using PDO , and all of a sudden you jump into old data fetching technique using mysql_*

My advice is to stick with PDO structure . SO you have to some little things

on line 6 use

```
$stmt->rowCount();
```

to get user row

then use

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

to get database rows , You'll get an object .

Now You just need to loop through object for example

```
foreach ( $data as $rows ){

         echo $rows->users;

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php 
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hangman");
 ?>

<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>Score</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usernames";
    $result = $db-query($sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
        <td><?php echo $row['users']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Scores']; ?></td>
        <?php
    }
 ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

give me a comment if any errors.

Comment: cheers for the code, but I used the other one because I been using PDO through out so I thought I might as well just stick to it @lyndact